# How to determine minimum supported OS version of my app?

Tags: centos, dependencies, c++, compatibility

**Background**

I'm making an C++ app that's supposed to run on Centos 7. Builds are being done on Centos 7.9, and I'm using C++11 and C++17 features, which limits backward compatibility with older versions of Centos 7. There is an installer that can perform some checks before user is able to run the app.

**Question**

How can I automatically determine minimal supported version of Centos 7 for the app I'm developing?

**What i have currently**

Right now, after building, I'm retrieving a list of the required libraries using `ldd` and `readelf` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242761/determine-direct-shared-object-dependencies-of-a-linux-binary ). With the list I'm able to compare what the user has to what my app needs, and if the user's version is lower than required, the installer tells him to upgrade. However, with this method my list tells me what are the versions of the libraries that I have on my build machine, not the oldest compatible versions of them.

What i've thought I'd do was I'd downgrade my build machine to some version of Centos 7 and - if the app compiles - say that's the lowest supported one. The installer would then compare user's version of library to the generated list. That being said, I'd like to have some sort of promise that newer versions are backward-compatible with the version I'd be using, and I couldn't find anything like that on Centos' or Red Hat's webpages. There are also security concerns about using older, unsupported version of OS.

Second option would be to only support whatever I have on my build machine, but that might require some users to upgrade, and they might not like it.

Third option is to build the app and try to run it on an old version of Centos.

---

Biggest part of my problem is lack of knowledge how to distribute Linux apps outside of the packet manager. On Windows you simply pack all DLLs with EXEs and you're good to go (most of the time). On Linux however you can't do that (I mean, you can mess with RPATH...).

Comment: Will you be distributing a compiled binary then, not the source?

Comment: @terdon Yes, it's not going to be an open source app.

Comment: @crueltear are you distributing your application as a RPM? It sounds like you are not. Are you talking about build dependencies or runtime dependencies, or both? Your first paragraph talks about C++11 and C++17 which are build dependencies because the correct version of the compiler is required which contains the minimum set of C++ features. Later, you talk about compatible library versions which is a runtime dependency.

Comment: @DanielDearlove Generally runtime dependencies, but  in this case both - if I use C++11 or newer runtime will be dependent on some specific version of libstdc++.so.
No, I'm not distributing as RPM, otherwise I'd be able to easily set all dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The **only** supported version of any RHEL `$release` is the `$latest` one, e.g. for 7 it will be 7.9. Targeting older releases is a waste of time and resources. If your potential clients are running something different than e.g. 7.9 they are welcoming severe security vulnerabilities.

> Biggest part of my problem is lack of knowledge how to distribute Linux apps outside of the packet manager.

- Release as a flatpak/snap/appimage (I generally dislike this approach but Linux distros have long buried [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base))
- If your app is open source, you could potentially link it statically with everything (a really bad idea)
- Distribute it in a source form and let those who need it, compile it on their own